# requests.get breaking the loop without error

Tags: python, python-requests, download

I'm making a movie downloading script
and I'm using requests to download the file like that

```
def Download(url, path): # last stage: downloading
try:
    req = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    
    fileSize=1
    start = last_print = monotonic()
    isContentLength = True
    bytesToGB=9.313225746154785*(10**-10)
    try:
        res = requests.head(url)
        fileSize = int(res.headers['content-length'])
        print(f"{bcolors.OKBLUE}File Size: {fileSize}  ({round(fileSize*bytesToGB,2)}GB){bcolors.ENDC}")
    except:
        isContentLength = False

    progress=0
    chunkSize = 1024
    lastSpeed = 0
    percent = 100
    with open(path, 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=chunkSize):
            progress += file.write(chunk)
            if isContentLength:
                now = monotonic()
                if now > last_print:
                    percent = (progress / fileSize) * 100
                    speedType = 'Kbps'
                    speed = round(progress / (now - start) / 1024)
                    
                    if speed >= 1000:
                        speedType = 'Mbps'
                        speed = round(speed / 1000, 1)
                    else:
                        speedType = 'Kbps'

                    print(f"\r{bcolors.OKGREEN}{progress}{bcolors.ENDC} / {fileSize} {bcolors.OKCYAN}{speed} {speedType}{bcolors.ENDC} {bcolors.OKGREEN}{round(percent, 2)}% {bcolors.ENDC} ", sep="", end="", flush=True)
                    lastSpeed = speed
    if percent < 100:
        Download(url, path) 

except:
    print(f"{bcolors.FAIL}Error (404){bcolors.ENDC}")
    print(f"{url}")
    return False
return True
```

now there is a problem that while the video is being downloading, for no reason the download stops with percent less than 100

this is a picture of what I mean to say
[image]

can you help me to know what causes this error ?

Comment: FYI, easier way to compute bytes to GB is `bytes / (1<<30)`.  Use 10 for KB, 20 for MB, 40 for TB, etc.

Comment: Get rid of the bare except handlers and see if you are getting an error.

Comment: Don't ever catch all exceptions with a bare `except` - you could be hiding actual issues with your code, and it breaks the ability to ctrl-C to terminate the program. You should only catch the _specific_ error types you expect to handle using that block

Comment: I did what you told me, but still the same problem, I think the problem from the server that I'm downloading from, and I see the only solution is to continue downloading instead of start it from beginning @PranavHosangadi

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).